# How do I programmatically register a user in Joomla and in JomSocial?

Tags: registration, joomla-1.5, jomsocial, angularjs

I have almost the same task as mentioned in [How do I programmatically activate a JomSocial user?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16779/how-do-i-programmatically-activate-a-jomsocial-user/30301#)(register new users from my angular app into Joomla).

How can I access the file, mentioned in the answer, from my external angular app to call the function `createUser()`?

I tried a post request, but it cannot access the file.